# Migración de SQL Server a MySQL solo importa las tablas y nos los procedimientos almacenados

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, odbc, migracion

Buenos días espero que se encuentren muy bien.

El motivo de mi consulta se debe a que estoy en proceso de migración de mi base de datos de SQL Server a un hosting de hostinger, el inconveniente es que hostinger solo me permite administrar mis bases de datos con phpmyadmin y esta solo tiene compatibilidad con MySql.

Entonces, ahora e instalado MySql para migrar mi base de datos de SQL Server a esta nueva y solo me hace la importación de las tablas perfectamente pero no migra mis procedimientos almacenados, vistas, triggers y funciones.

Me a tocado prácticamente ir corrigiendo la sintaxis de mis procedimientos almacenados uno a uno para poder ejecutarlos en MySQL y crearlos

Mis tablas junto con la información se migraron desde MySQL desde la opción DATABASE>MIGRATIN WIZARD>CREÉ LA CONEXION CON BD DE SQL SERVER CON ODBC ADMINITRATOR

Luego de eso empiezo en la otra opción de START MIGRATION hago todo el proceso de escoger todas las tablas y hasta me permite seleccionar mis objetos de la tabla, pero a la final me salta un error y solo termina exportando mis tablas únicamente.

Agradezco mucho me puedan ayudar e buscado herramientas y solo me han permitido exportar solo tablas.

--Paso # 1
[image: PASO # 1]

--Paso # 2
[image: PASO # 2]

--Paso # 3
[image: PASO # 3]

--Paso # 4
[image: VERIFICACIÓN]

--Paso # 5
[image: Me dice que no hay errores]

--Paso # 6
[image: PASO # 6]

--Paso # 7
[image: VALIDACIÓN]

--Paso # 8 (Aquí es donde se muestra un error haciendo el "Copy data to target RDBMS", creo que esa puede ser la razón por al cual no copia los procedimientos almacenados, triggers, funciones y vistas)
[image: MENSAJE DE CONFIRMACION DE TABLAS]

Comment: 1. Recuerda que mayúsculas en internet = GRITAR. 2. Mencionaste un error. Y el error, ¿es? No olvides [edit] tu pregunta para agregar más detalles.

Comment: ¿Y qué dicen los logs?

Comment: Es probable que no puedas migrar automáticamente los procedimientos y funciones debido a la incompatibilidad entre un lenguaje y otro. Hay funciones que no existen en ambos y hay procesos que deben cambiar por completo.

Comment: Habrá alguna herramienta algo así como un conversor de sintaxis? Esto a sido duro, tengo aproximadamente 300 procedimientos y hacerlos uno a uno esta siendo complicado.

Comment: No confiaría en un conversor de sintaxis. Aunque lo hiciera muy bien, tendría que revisar procedimiento por procedimiento y función por función para asegurarme de que todo funcione correctamente.